How do I run script against every computer in an OU
I need to fix this; it just pulls the local server folders vs the remote computer folders - I know I'm missing $PC in a few places but I'm not sure this will even work as expected.
Expectation: to remove the data in the signatures folder for every user on a computer
$OUpath = 'ou=GPO Testing Ground,ou=Workstations,ou=Domain Computers,dc=test,dc=com'
$PCList = (Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $OUpath | Select-object -expandproperty Name)

ForEach ($PC in $PCList) 
{
    Write-host $PC
    If (Test-Connection $PC -Count 1 -Quiet)
    {
        $TopFolder = 'c$\users'
        $SigFolder = 'AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures'
        $FolderList = Get-ChildItem $TopFolder -Directory -Exclude default, Public
        write-host $folderlist
        foreach ($Item in $FolderList)
            {
                write-host (Join-Path -Path \\$PC\$Item -ChildPath $SigFolder)
                if (Test-Path (Join-Path -Path $Item -ChildPath $SigFolder))
                {
                    $compPath = "$Item" + "\" + "$SigFolder" + "\*"
                    #Remove-Item $compPath -Recurse -WhatIf
                    Write-host $compPath
                }
            }
    }
}



Looks like your missing $PC so its searching the local C: not the remote computer.
Modify this to suit you needs.
$OUpath = 'ou=GPO Testing Ground,ou=Workstations,ou=Domain Computers,dc=test,dc=com'
$PCList = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $OUpath

ForEach ($PC in $PCList.dnshostname) 
{
    Write-host $PC
    If (Test-Connection $PC -Count 1 -Quiet)
    {
        #$TopFolder = 'c$\users' # This is the error - no $PC, its looking for the local C:\ not the remote system
        $TopFolder = '\\$PC\c$\users'
        $SigFolder = 'AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures'
        $FolderList = Get-ChildItem $TopFolder -Directory -Exclude default, Public
        write-host $folderlist
        # Use "Fullname" for the complete filepath
        foreach ($Item in $FolderList.Fullname) 
            {
                #write-host (Join-Path -Path "\\$PC\$Item" -ChildPath $SigFolder)
                $Folderpath = Join-Path -Path "$Item" -ChildPath $SigFolder
                write-host "Testing path to $Folderpath"
                if (Test-Path $Folderpath)
                {
                    #$compPath = "$Item" + "\" + "$SigFolder" + "\*"
                    #Remove-Item $compPath -Recurse -WhatIf
                    #Write-host $compPath
                    $SigFolderpath = "$Folderpath\$Sigfolder"
                    Write-host -for Yellow "Attempting to remove $SigFolderpath"
                    Remove-Item $SigFolderpath -Recurse -WhatIf                 
                }
                else
                {
                    Write-Warning "Test-Path failed for $PC"
                    Write-Host -for Red $Error[0].Exception.Message
                }
            }
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Warning "Test-Testconnection failed for $PC"
        Write-Host -for Red $Error[0].Exception.Message
    }
}

